# What is the correct way to add Glimpse to a MVC project that references an EF project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, glimpse

I recently discovered how useful [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) can be for developing ASP.NET MVC5 + EF6 applications and would like to include it within the new application I've been tasked to create.

While the process of adding the Glimpse MVC5 and EF6 nuget packages to the default MVC5 / EF6 combo project is pretty straightfoward, I can't seem to find any information on the correct way to setup Glimpse for an MVC5 project that has a separated EF6 project.

If I have the following solution structure:

> Solution
>   |__ EF6.Models
>   |__ MVC5.Website

Do I need to add the Glimpse.EF6 package to both the EF6.Models project and the MVC5.Website project? or, do I just need to add it to the MVC5.Website project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add Glimpse.Mvc* and Glimpse.Ef* (and any other Glimpse packages you want) to your web project.

Don't worry about installing anything Glimpse specific in any other projects.